# Does pymongo require mongodb to be installed locally?

Tags: python, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

In my AWS production environment I currently have 3 instances running a mongodb replicaset. I have created a separate instance that contains a web server and all my python application code. Do I need to install mongodb locally on this machine to connect to my replicaset with pymongo?

Comment: the documentation does not list `mongodb` as a dependency of pymongo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Just create a client object on a different host:

```
import pymongo
client = pymongo.MongoClient('servername')
```